# How can I find the minimum of $f(x,y)=y$, if $y^3-x^2=0$

Tags: calculus

I want to find the minimum of the function $f(x,y)=y,$ and constrain $y^3-x^2=0.$

At first I use Lagrange multipler to find the minimum,but it seen that Lagrange multipler doesn't work.

So I am wondering how can I solve this kind of question, in which case I can't apply Lagrange multipler,and why it doesn't work,thank you very much.

Comment: $f(x,\sqrt {y^3} \ )=\sqrt {y^3}$ so the minimum should be $f(x,y)=0$

Comment: I understand,thank.

Answer (score 2):

Minimize $y$ such that $y^3 = x^2$.  Since $x^2 \geq 0$ regardless of $x$, and $y = x = 0$ satisfies the constraint, the minimum is $0$, occurring at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Now to Lagrange multipliers.  We first resolve the points where the gradient of the constraint is zero.  (These are typically called singular points in the method of Lagrange multipliers.)
$$  \nabla_{(x,y)} (y^3 - x^2) = (2x, 3y^2) = (0,0)  $$
only when $(x,y) = (0,0)$.  So we must determine whether that point satisfies our constraint (which it does) and we must remember that this is a candidate minimum, $0$, of our objective function.  (As a procedural analogy, checking constraint singularities is similar to remembering to check the endpoints in a one-dimensional optimization problem.)

Then, we wish to study conditions under which 
$$  \nabla_{(x,y,\lambda)} (y) - \lambda(y^3 - x^2) = (2 x \lambda, 1 - 3 \lambda y^2, x^2 - y^3) = (0,0,0)  $$

From the first component of the gradient, either $x = 0$ or $\lambda = 0$.

- If $x = 0$, the third component forces $-y^3 = 0$, so $y = 0$ and the second member of the gradient vector cannot be zero, a contradiction.
- If $\lambda = 0$, the equation again fails in the second member of the gradient.

Therefore, the Lagrange function does not find additional candidate minima.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question. Is it  necessary to check the gradient of the constraint is (0,0) each time when I try to use Lagrange multipler?

Comment: @user664674 : ... only if you want to find extrema where the constraint(s) are singular.  The question you have asked is an excellent example of why you should check the singularities of the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
L(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)
$$

with $f(x,y) = y,\ \ g(x,y) = y^3-x^2 = 0$

According to the Lagrange condition, the stationary points should satisfy:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\
1\end{array}\right)+\lambda \left(\begin{array}{c}-2x\\
3y^2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\
0\end{array}\right)\\
y^3-x^2=0
$$

Here we need that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ be aligned which implies on $x=0$

Now following with

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\
1\end{array}\right)+\lambda \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\
3\epsilon^2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\
0\end{array}\right)
$$

we see that any $\epsilon \ne 0$ would suffice but the constraint $\epsilon^3-0^2=0$ implies on $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}$ as a degenerate solution.

Concluding, the only stationary point is a degenerate one and is at $(0,0)$.